# Why className not taking state's value?

Tags: reactjs

I have been trying to set active tab in my sidebar, but seems there's some error because value is not being set in the className.

Following is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import RMS from "./pins/RMS.png";
import IAAS from "./pins/IAAS.png";
import MINIGRID from "./pins/Minigrid(2).png";
import HOME from "./pins/ROOFTOP.png";
import ROOFTOP from "./pins/Rooftop(2).png";
class Sidebar extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={activetab:''}
    this.handleclick=this.handleclick.bind(this)
  }
  handleclick(event){
    console.log('handleclick',event)
    this.setState({activetab:event})
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.activetab)
    return (
      <aside className="main_sidebar">
        <ul  >
          <Link key='home'  to="/">
            <li title="Home" onClick={this.handleclick.bind(this,'home')} className={this.state.activetab=='home'? 'active':''}>
              <i>
                <img
                  alt="home"
                  style={{ width: "45%", marginLeft: "3px" }}
                  src={HOME}
                />
              </i>
            </li>
          </Link>
          <Link key="rms"  to="/rms">
          <li title="RMS" onClick={this.handleclick.bind(this,'rms')} className={this.state.activetab=='rms'? 'active':''}>

              <i>
                <img alt="rms" src={RMS} />
              </i>
          </li>
          </Link>
          <li title="IAAS">
            <a
              target="_blank"
              rel="noopener noreferrer"
              href="../IAAS/menubar.html"
            >
              <i>
                <img alt="IAAS" src={IAAS} />
              </i>
            </a>
          </li>

            <li title="Solar Rooftop">
            <a className="disabled">
              <i>
                <img alt="Rooftop" src={ROOFTOP} />
              </i>
            </a>
            </li>

          <li title="Minigrid">
            <a className="disabled">
              <i>
                <img alt="Minigrid" src={MINIGRID} />
              </i>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </aside>
    );
  }
}

export default Sidebar;
```

If you notice the console in the render, it always gives a blank value.
Please comment if anything unclear about the code.
your help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: So you mean to say the value of event is always empty?

Comment: Why mix `Link` and `li` with `onClick`?

Comment: @DhananjaiPai yes

Comment: @DavinTryon link is used for routing . Should i write onclick in `li`  ?

Comment: You have pass the event in `onClick` event and get value from `event.currentTarget`. Please refer this https://codesandbox.io/s/mzr7mnn358

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be binding `this` multiple times. Once inside the constructor and then from the onClick handler

Remove the bind from the constructor and it should work fine.

Comment: removed it but still same issue

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the correct value to the state value when handling your event :

```
handleclick(event){
    console.log('handleclick',event)
    this.setState({activetab:event})
}
```

Should be:

```
handleclick(event){
    this.setState({ activetab: 'home'})
}
```

Passing the full click event to your state will not be useful.

Now your ternary condition in your JSX will return the correct value :

```
this.state.activetab === 'home' ? 'active':''
```

You could also convert all your class functions to arrow function. This will allow you to not bind them :

```
handleclick = event => {
    console.log('handleclick',event)
    this.setState({activetab:event})
}

constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={activetab:''}
}

<li title="RMS" onClick={this.handleclick}
```

You were also binding your `handleclick` function twice

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you are triggering `Link` with the click and therefore, you are re-mounting the component on every click.

Maybe you should derive your tab state based on the location path?

```
render() {
    console.log(this.state.activetab)
    return (
      <aside className="main_sidebar">
        <ul  >
          <Link key='home'  to="/">
            <li title="Home" className={this.props.location.pathname ==='/'? 'active':''}>
              <i>
                <img
                  alt="home"
                  style={{ width: "45%", marginLeft: "3px" }}
                  src={HOME}
                />
              </i>
            </li>
          </Link>
          <Link key="rms"  to="/rms">
          <li title="RMS" className={this.props.location.pathname ==='/rms'? 'active':''}>
              <i>
                <img alt="rms" src={RMS} />
              </i>
          </li>
          </Link>
          <li title="IAAS">
            <a
              target="_blank"
              rel="noopener noreferrer"
              href="../IAAS/menubar.html"
            >
              <i>
                <img alt="IAAS" src={IAAS} />
              </i>
            </a>
          </li>

            <li title="Solar Rooftop">
            <a className="disabled">
              <i>
                <img alt="Rooftop" src={ROOFTOP} />
              </i>
            </a>
            </li>

          <li title="Minigrid">
            <a className="disabled">
              <i>
                <img alt="Minigrid" src={MINIGRID} />
              </i>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </aside>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Yeah i think u r right, on my route change the same component is reintialised, hence making the value blank. So, how to derive tab state based on location path